# cross-browser tableborder-color resetting

Tags: css, cross-browser

Whats the best way to reset and then rewrite the tableborder-color for the most common browsers, let's say FF, Opera, Safari and Chrome so that it will look the same as in IE.

IE:

[image]
<sub>(source: [datapeak.net](http://datapeak.net/ScreenHunter_05%20Jun.%2017%2013.15.gif))</sub>

Firefox, etc:

[image]
<sub>(source: [datapeak.net](http://datapeak.net/ScreenHunter_04%20Jun.%2017%2013.14.gif))</sub>

it seems that a browser selector is neccessary, because different browsers interpret the same hexadecimal values differently.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use css instead? Something like the following will give you a cross-browser look:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.myclass
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 2px solid green;
        width: 300px;
    }
    table.myclass td
    {
        border: 2px solid green;
    }
</style>
```